# If function, finding a match on the last 3 characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got the following formula that looks at a cell, and if it contains the characters "IDE" anywhere on the text then it puts a "Y" on the column, otherwise an "N".

```
=IF(COUNTIF(J1021, "*IDE*"),"Y", "N")
```

What I want to do is actually modify this formula so it only puts a "Y" on the cell if the last 3 characters of the cell are "IDE", not just a match anywhere.

That way I can have something like this.

[image]

Comment: Use `RIGHT()` Function to determine that, with an `IF()` Logic!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I tried that, but I don't know how to insert the RIGHT function inside the if function without it giving me an error.

Comment: Try this `=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)="IDE","Y","N")`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That worked! My issue is that I was still trying to use the "COUNTIFS" funciton to obtain a partial match which did not work. If you submit that as an answer I can select it as an answer to my question.

Comment: Why not : =IF(COUNTIF(J1021, "*IDE"),"Y", "N")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RIGHT()` Function

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)="IDE","Y","N")
```

You can also do a **`BOOLEAN LOGIC`** here,

[image: BOOLEAN_LOGIC]

• Simply enter the formula in cell **C1**

```
=(RIGHT(A1,3)="IDE")*1
```

And then Custom format the cell by pressing `CTRL` + `1` --> `Format Cells` --> `Number Tab` --> `Category` --> `Custom` --> `Type` -->

```
[=1]"Y";[=0]"N";
```

But note the cells will show `1` for a `TRUE` value & `0` for a `FALSE` value.

Comment: What is wrong with the OP's logic and just control with the use of the wildcards? Then it is easy to get left, mid or right positioning...

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, there is nothing wrong, I thought using `RIGHT()` should be the easy one, so I shared, its personal based

Comment: Sir, I prefer using `BOOLEAN` Logic however your option is also good there is nothing wrong, we are sharing our knowledge, just voted you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the function you have already and edit it like so:
[image]

```
IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*IDE"),"Y","N")
```

Comment: What does having a single * on the left of the formula does?

Comment: `*` it means wildcard character to represent any series of character while `?` to represent any single character!

Comment: @Sam that allows any characters PRIOR to IDE which is what you asked for, based onyour own formula. You could also find any that START with IDE with any characters after... BUT since you have already accepted an answer I won't expand my answer.