# Trouble with fuzzy matching columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

We have a long list of organizations that we are trying to match to another long list of organizations. Normally, I would just use an index/match formula to match the 2 columns together. However, they both utilize organization names and the spelling can vary mildly.

For example, one column might refer to Organization A as "Tanner Health" and another might refer to it as "Tanner Healthcare". Another example, one column might refer to Organization B as "The Tanner Health Institute" and another might refer to it as "Tanner Health Institute". There are countless examples, but the idea is that we want to try and get the closest possible match between the 2 columns.

It is totally possible that a Organization in column 1 might not exist in column 2, in which case, we don't want it to return anything.

If it helps at all, we also have information about each organizations state and zip code. So, I considered an array formula that matches Zip code, State, and then does the best fuzzy match to the available options.

I am struggling to find a formula that can do a fuzzy match of the 2 columns, and am looking for suggestions on the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. @BigBen I am using Google Sheets.

Comment: Have you tried wildcards: "* Tanner * ") ?

Comment: No I have not, what are wildcards?

Comment: Well, if you missed the (obvious) example I did with Tanner then have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71664804/4961700

Comment: Is there a way to utilize wildcards in a formula? If column A is organization names, and column B is organization names -- and I am looking to run a match over the entire list. How can I leverage wildcards in a larger overarching match formula?

Comment: It's difficult to add anything meaningful to this topic in the absence of any actual data set. Consider adding a reasonable data set to your post that covers a realistic array of what you mean by entries that "can vary mildly." Better yet, include that in your post *and* provide a link to an actual spreadsheet that contains such an example data set. Formulas are written around specifics, and at this point, we have one example in "Tanner": not enough to build around. For instance, your one example implies that every company name will include "Health," but that is likely not so.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903283/erik-tyler) mentioned

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result